# How to create a complexType where elements can be in any order, and one element must occur at least once

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I have a complex type like:

```
<xs:complexType name="blocks">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="BlockA" type="blockA" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xs:element name="BlockB" type="blockB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
<xs:attribute name="Use" type="xs:boolean" use="required" /></xs:complexType>
```

but it is not configured how I would like.

I want it so that

1. Elements 'BlockA' and 'BlockB' can be in ANY order
2. BlockA has to occur at least 1 time.
3. BlockB can occur 0 or more times.

The XSD order indicators 'sequence' and 'choice' don't seem to provide such options.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this in XSD 1.0 I believe it can be expressed as

```
sequence
  element name=BlockB min=0 max=unbounded
  element name=BlockA min=1 max=1
  choice min=0 max=unbounded
    element name=BlockA min=1 max=1
    element name=BlockB min=1 max=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and a solution is replacing the `xs:sequence` by `xs:all`. Unfortunately this solution works only in XSD-1.1, because XSD-1.0 has the restriction that `maxOccurs` can only be `0` or `1` (see comments below).

```
<xs:complexType name="blocks">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="BlockA" type="blockA" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="BlockB" type="blockB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:all>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="Use" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

This has worked in my example code.

---

**EDIT:**
I used the following XSD as a test-case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
  elementFormDefault="unqualified"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="root" type="blocks" />

    <xs:complexType name="blocks">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="BlockA" type="blockA" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="BlockB" type="blockB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="Use" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="blockA">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="blockB">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

And my example code samples were the following:

1. - BlockA >= 1
   - BlockB >= 1

   for this code:

   ```
   <root Name="ThisIsAName" Use="true">
       <BlockB>DEF</BlockB>    
       <BlockA>ABC</BlockA>
       <BlockA>ABC</BlockA>
       <BlockA>ABC</BlockA>
       <BlockA>ABC</BlockA>
       <BlockB>DEF</BlockB>    
   </root>
   ```

   **===> VALID!!!**
2. - BlockA >= 1
   - BlockB  = 0

   for this code:

   ```
   <root Name="ThisIsAName" Use="true">
       <BlockA>ABC</BlockA>   
       <BlockA>ABC</BlockA>   
   </root>
   ```

   **===> VALID!!!**
3. - BlockA  = 0
   - BlockB >= 1

   for this code:

   ```
   <root Name="ThisIsAName" Use="true">
       <BlockB>DEF</BlockB>    
       <BlockB>DEF</BlockB>    
   </root>
   ```

   **===> FAIL!!!**
4. - BlockA = 0
   - BlockB = 0

   for this code:

   ```
   <root Name="ThisIsAName" Use="true">
   </root>
   ```

   **===> FAIL!!!**

So with XSD-1.1 everything does work.

Comment: Hi zx485, thanks for your reply. I'm not sure `<xs:all>` will do it as "The <all> indicator specifies that the child elements can appear in any order, and that each child element must occur only once". I specified that each element can occurs  >1 times.

Comment: Yes, I see that 0 occurrences are possible. I was trying to highlight that the <all> indicator only allows 0 or 1 occurances. But I need the possibility of the  elements to occur > 1 times.

Comment: As I mentioned (and tested) - multiple occurrences are possible and valid with `xs:all`.

Comment: OK, thank you. I haven't tested as yet as I'm replying on my mobile.

Comment: Hi zx485, I've edited my *.xsd file to match your sample above, but I'm getting a squiggly in Visual Studio saying "all is not the only particle in a group, or is being used as an extension.". Any idea what that means?

Comment: I'm also getting squiggly warnings for the use of 'unbounded' as the value for maxOccurs

Comment: I don't know how you tested it, but even if I ignore the squiggly warnings and run the code I get a schema exception. So, sadly, I don't think this will work.

Comment: I added the samples to my solution.

Comment: In XSD 1.0 the maxOccurs of a particle within xs:all must be 0 or 1. In XSD 1.1 it can be any value. So I think we are at cross-purposes here about which XSD version we are talking about.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Thank you very much. This is the root cause of our miscommunication, because I tested this with an XSD-1.1 processor being unaware of this restriction. If you know of an XSD-1.0 solution, I'd be interested.

Comment: The constraint can probably be expressed awkwardly in 1.0 using a content model such as `B* A (A|B)*`

Comment: @MichaelKay and zx485, thank you both so much for your help. I am very new to XSD and clearly still have a lot to learn! I am using the .NET Framework XmlSchema and XmlSchemaSet classes to do the processing. Do you have any idea if these can be made to use XSD 1.1? Things would certainly be a lot simpler if it could.

Comment: Microsoft haven't updated their XML technology for the best part of 20 years; if you want access to the latest W3C standards you need to use libraries from third parties. XSD 1.1 is implemented in Altova, Saxon, and Xerces.

Comment: @MichaelKay, thanks for the advice. In the meantime your solution is doing a great job!