# XSD 1.0: How to validate 4 elements in any order, each element occuring once only, but at least one of the elements must occur once only

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

My scenario is as follows:

1. I have 4 different elements which can appear in any order
2. Each of these 4 elements can appear a maximum of once only. That is, 0 or 1 times.
3. At least one of these 4 elements must occur.

Sadly, I am constrained to use the .NET Framework classes to process a Schema, which means I am looking for a solution using XSD 1.0.

Here is some sample XML which obviously doesn't work!

```
<xs:complexType name="Groups">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Group1" type="group1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="Group2" type="group2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="Group3" type="group3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="Group4" type="group4" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
 </xs:sequence></xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSD: How to create a complexType where elements can be in any order, and one element must occur at least once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314105/xsd-how-to-create-a-complextype-where-elements-can-be-in-any-order-and-one-ele)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `<xs:sequence>` with `<xs:all>`, this will

1. Allow any order for the Group# nodes
2. Allow each element a max occurs of 1

The only thing that the below does not validate is that at least 1 of the elements occurs.

```
    <xs:element name="Groups">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Group1" type="Group1" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Group2" type="Group2" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Group3" type="Group3" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Group4" type="Group4" />
        </xs:all>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

If you really want to verify that at least 1 of the element occurs with any combination of elements after it, it becomes a very complex large schema with lots of Choice and Sequence nodes and setting the minOccurs to 0 in various places.  The below schema will validate any file starting with Group1 and any combination of the other Groups.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO57321841" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO57321841" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Groups">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1">
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Group1" type="Group1" />
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Group2" type="Group2" />
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Group3" type="Group3" />
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Group4" type="Group4" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Group4" type="Group4" />
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Group3" type="Group3" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:choice>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Group3" type="Group3" />
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Group2" type="Group2" />
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Group4" type="Group4" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Group4" type="Group4" />
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Group2" type="Group2" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:choice>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Group4" type="Group4" />
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Group2" type="Group2" />
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Group3" type="Group3" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Group3" type="Group3" />
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Group2" type="Group2" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:choice>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:choice>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Group2" type="Group2" />
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Group3" type="Group3" />
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Group4" type="Group4" />
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="Group1" />
  <xs:complexType name="Group2" />
  <xs:complexType name="Group3" />
  <xs:complexType name="Group4" />
</xs:schema>
```